# Mantain dutycycle when you left the python script on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I have a Raspberry Pi (mod.B or B+ or 2 or 3) and I connect one GPIO to a led to make it dimmable. Everything works ok. If I run this python lines:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(23,1000)
pwm.start(0)
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(100)
time.sleep(1)
```

I have the led at 100% of its bright. Now, when I exit the python script after a time.sleep() of 1 sec, my led is off... but I don't have set GPIO.cleanup() of stuff like that. My goal si to set a new dutycycle then maintain it forever after the end of the script.

Comment: I would guess that python does a cleanup when it exits.

Comment: it should not switch off the pin at exit [see docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/), but it won't continue a PWM. I am not sure if switching off the pwm sets the pin to down or if its just random what state is active when the script exited. But you probably can just set the pin to full on before exit and the led stays on at 100%.